# com.example.mainactivity E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android

I am doing a project. But I am getting error repeatedly for 3 days long and can't solve it. This is my main activity:

```
AlertDialog dialog;
IFirebaseLoadListener iFirebaseLoadListener;
RecyclerView my_recyler_view;
DatabaseReference mydata;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //init

    mydata= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyData");
    dialog=new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(this).build();
    iFirebaseLoadListener=this;

    //View

    my_recyler_view =findViewById(R.id.my_recyclr_view);
    my_recyler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
    my_recyler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    //Load Data

    getFirebaseData();
}

private void getFirebaseData() {

    dialog.show();

    mydata.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            List<ItemGroup> itemGroups=new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot groupSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                ItemGroup itemGroup = new ItemGroup();
                itemGroup.setHeaderTitle(groupSnapShot.child("headerTitle").getValue(true).toString());
                GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<ItemData>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<ItemData>>() {
                    @Override
                    public int hashCode() {
                        return super.hashCode();
                    }
                };

                itemGroup.setListItem(groupSnapShot.child("listItem").getValue(genericTypeIndicator));

                itemGroups.add(itemGroup);
            }
            iFirebaseLoadListener.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(itemGroups);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            iFirebaseLoadListener.onFirebaseLocationFailed(databaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onFirebaseLoadSuccess(List<ItemGroup> itemGroupList) {

    MyItemGroupAdapter adapter=new MyItemGroupAdapter(this,itemGroupList);
    my_recyler_view.setAdapter(adapter);

    dialog.dismiss();

}

@Override
public void onFirebaseLocationFailed(String message) {

    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dialog.dismiss();

}
```

}

Here is my stack trace

> 2019-10-13 11:56:39.671 1870-1880/? E/SurfaceFlinger:
>   ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
>
> 2019-10-13 11:56:39.705 1870-1870/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer
>   name: changing
>   com.example.mainactivity/com.example.mainactivity.MainActivity to
>   com.example.mainactivity/com.example.mainactivity.MainActivity#1
>
> 2019-10-13 11:56:39.710 1597-1643/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc:
>   Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
>
> 2019-10-13 11:56:39.720 1597-1597/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc:
>   Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
>
> 2019-10-13 11:56:39.736 1597-1643/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc:
>   Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
>
> 2019-10-13 11:56:39.776 7854-7854/com.example.mainactivity
>   E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout -- when making a todo list app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034951/e-recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-when-making-a-todo-list)

Comment: But how can i correct my error from your previous answer with this specific code? please help on this, I have stuck three days on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you're missing is setting the adapter to the `recyclerView` in `onCreate()`.

- First, declare this two as global variables before `onCreate()`:

  `List<ItemGroup> itemGroups;
   MyItemGroupAdapter adapter;`
- then, in the `onCreate()`, assign them:

  ```
  itemGroups=new ArrayList<>();
  adapter=new MyItemGroupAdapter(this,itemGroupList);
  my_recyler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
  ```
- Then Update the `itemGroups` as you're doing.
- After that, in the `onFirebaseLoadSuccess()`, simply update the data as:
  `adapter.updateData(myNewData);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 1):

You should create and set the Adapter inside `onCreate()` and when data updates, let the adapter know that data has been updated using `yourAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged()` method from the `onFirebaseLoadSuccess()` method