# Android - E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement a recycler view into my app, but I'm getting the above error. It seems like I'm not setting the adapter in the correct place.

To give you an overview, I need to search the database based on the result of a different query, so I created a method `populateViews(query)` inside the MainActivity.class to push the result of the query in string format out of the `onDataChanged()`

I checked the log, and it seems the code is going into the populateView method but not able to find the adapter.

The `populateView` method is like:

```
protected void populateView(Query query) {

    menuRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    menuRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Menu> options;
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Menu, FirebaseViewHolder> adapter;

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Menu>().setQuery(query, Menu.class).build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Menu, FirebaseViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FirebaseViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Menu model) {

                holder.dishName.setText(model.getDishName());
                holder.dishPrice.setText(model.getDishPrice());

                Log.i("name", model.getDishName());
                Log.i("price", model.getDishPrice());

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FirebaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new FirebaseViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(MenuListActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.menu_list_layout, parent, false));
            }
    };

    menuRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

EDIT: Added layout manager, but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Have you added `LayoutManager` in your `menuRecyclerView` like this `menuRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);`

Comment: Post code of your menuRecyclerView!

Comment: menuRecyclerView is the name of the recyclerView in the UI

Comment: I added the LayoutManager, but still the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No adapter attached; skipping layout skipped 1 till 2 frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666618/no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-skipped-1-till-2-frames)

Comment: You should only notify the adapter inside the callback. Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set layoutmanager before attaching the adapter. Below is the example of layoutmanager that helps populating data in vertical manner.

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
menuRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Comment: I added, but still the same error.

Comment: try giving an orientation as I have added in the answer

Comment: I added orientation, but still the same error.
`LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
menuRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

Comment: is your recycler view visible in your device? This may be an error but it does not give ANR

Comment: No data is being displayed

Comment: Do you have data in options and menu in adapter

Comment: can u please post your xml